# can not add shipping cost in order grid

Tags: shipping, order-grid

my requirement is to add shipping cost in sales order grid,i added below code in _preparecolumns(),

```
$this->addColumn('base_shipping_amount', array(
    'header' => $helper->__('Shipping Amount (Base)'),
    'index'  => 'base_shipping_amount'
));
```

and added below code in _prepareCollection()

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(array('p' => 'sales/order_payment'), 'main_table.entity_id = p.parent_id', array(
    'payment_method' => 'method'
))
```

its giving me error . Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: magento 1 or 2?

Comment: magento 1.9.3.8

Comment: base_shipping_amount is not present on sales_flat_order_grid table. You need to join  sales_flat_order to your collection. Do you want a working code?

Comment: how to do that ? could you please explain me in detail ?

Comment: Yes please , it would be helpful if you provide me working code

Comment: I have added my answer. Please check its a working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

to local directory

> app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

And change the function _prepareCollection like below:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('base_shipping_amount'=>'base_shipping_amount'));        
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

And the below block the position you want under _prepareColumns

```
$this->addColumn('base_shipping_amount', array(
    'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Cost'),
    'width' => '80px',
    'type'  => 'currency',
    'index' => 'base_shipping_amount',
    'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
));
```

This is for show shipping cost. You can join payment method with the same collection by following same steps.

Hope this help!

Comment: thanks sukumar for your time , but it didn't worked . its giving below error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'shipping_method' in where clause is ambiguous,

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: its not working sukumar :(

Comment: whats the error you are getting? Did you join some more tables?

Comment: your code added the shipping cost column but its not getting data to the rows

Comment: It should work as it is working code I have checked. I think you are missing something.

Comment: Happy to Help. Upvote please.

Comment: happy to upvote sukumar , but need 15 reputation for that action , sorry :)

Comment: Sure no issues. When you reach then try :)

Answer (score 0):

Change below function code

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
         $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('base_shipping_amount'=>'base_shipping_amount'));        
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

will show shipping price 
[image]

Comment: sorry prashant , shipping price column not added with your changes , instead "bill to name ","ship to name" columns became empty.

Comment: Check updated code